# "Document has no pages" on iReport and nothing on OpenReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am having an issue with JasperReports I can not solve. I am using Eclipse, OpenReports 3.2 and IReport 3.7

The issue I am having is that the report does nothing. When I preview the report in IReport I can at least get a "Document has no pages" message but when I try to open it using OpenReports it doesn't do anything. I get the open reports header and the copyright message but nothing between them.

I was able to track it down to line 150 in ReportRunAction.java in OpenReports. That line is:

```
jasperPrint = jasperEngine.fillReport(reportInput);
```

At least that is the line the page dies on. It trips the catch block that the line is inside of but the error is empty. When I try to print the description it is null. I can't swear that the issue isn't that parameter. Through looking around all I have been able to find is something about how the report needs to be compiled with the same version of the jasperreports.jar that OpenReports uses. I have no idea how to tell if/what version of jasper reports is being bundled into the .jasper file though.

Is that my problem? If so how do I tell/set the version of the jar that gets bundled? If not; help!

Answer (score 4):

The no pages messages comes out when the report has not records or you discarded all of them with a wrong filter expression.

There are a couple of things you can try:

1. set the filter expression to:

   new Boolean (true)

This will in some way reset your filter expression.

- Right click your jasper report
- properties
- *find more.*..

  and Set the report property **"When no data"** to **"All sections no details"** so you can see at least the rest of the report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Detail Bandeport, then you will need a Data Query for the report. Since it's returning "No Pages" in iReport, then you either don't have a query. Or simply your query is not returning any rows.

In old iReport, from Data menu, choose Report Query and write your query here. If you want only one record (i.e. Detail band only one time) you can use a dummy table. Like:

```
SELECT 'a' FROM DUMMY
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to use the Detail Band, you have the option to view the other bands without using a query. From `Edit` menu, choose `Report Properties`, under `More...` tab, set the flag `When no data` to `All Sections, no detail`

Your problem is not exceptions or errors, it's just no data to show.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I know the report works because it is running on the live server. I am trying to set up a development environment on my computer. I am fine with getting no pages in iReport because that means it IS working and I just need different filter critera or something. My problem is when I run it through OpenReports it doesn't do anything.

Comment: In that case, im not sure, but since you are saying it catches an exception with no error, that could be a bug in OpenReport.

Answer (score 2):

Any Empty Datasource will do the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when using IReports when I had a subreport that only contained other subreports and no actual query. Adding a dummy query as medopal suggests fixes the `no pages` error and allows things to run correctly.

See also: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=49315

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing this error for a while. In my case, this error occurred because of an image. If you have images in your report file, you will be forced to fill image with valid data when you wanna use report. If you don't, you will see this error "Document has no page". To address this problem just set "on error type" field in properties window (just click on image you'll see the property window) to "blank".

Strong wish.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem and got after searching problem, that I did not provide password to connection.

so I add these lines to my java code.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stock_mngt","root","your password");
```

now my code works.