# Jasper the document has no page

Tags: jasper-reports, netbeans-7

I am trying the jasper report plugin with NetBeans.
I created my connection (test is okay)
I created the jrxml
and I try to preview it.

It is compiled automatically (the .jasper appears) and I have a message saying  : "the document has no page".

I read the problem could be the datasource that is empty but it is not the case.. so I decided to make a very simple jrxml (static : only text with no reference to any field of the database)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD JasperReport//EN"   "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

    <jasperReport name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="1500" columnWidth="535"  leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
        <background>
            <band/>
        </background>
        <title>
            <band height="79"/>
        </title>
        <pageHeader>
            <band height="35"/>
        </pageHeader>
        <columnHeader>
            <band height="61"/>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
          <band height="696">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-23" x="0" y="274" width="449" height="134"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
                    <font size="11" pdfFontName="Tiffy.ttf" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Vous avez reçu il y a quelques mois une attestation de la Caisse Primaire d'Assurance Maladie destinée à réduire le coût de votre adhésion à une complémentaire santé.\n\n"+
"Si vous rencontrez des difficultés dans vos démarches d'accès aux droits et aux soins, le Service social de l'Assurance Maladie est à votre disposition pour vous informer, vous conseiller et vous accompagner.\n\n" + 
"Aussi, je propose de vous rencontrer à votre domicile le : "]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
      </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

same think it compiles but I have the message

---

So I added those two lines :

```
<noData>no Data</noData>
<queryString>select * from dual</queryString>
```

Nothing is displayed obviously but the same message.. so connection seems alright no ?

Comment: This link may help you... [The Document has no page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47102519/4783846)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you only have static texts in the body of your report, if your sql for the report is empty, jasper displays nothing by default.  Try adding "select 1 as dummy" as your query and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Try an empty query and see the result. From this [CodeRanch forum post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/62787/open-source/Jasper-Reports-empty-report) I extracted the following:

> When your query yields no results, there're 3 options that are
>   provided by JR that you could make use of: (a) generate empty report
>   (PDF), i.e., no pages (b) generate a single blank page report (c)
>   generate a report showing all sections, except the detail section
>
> This can be done by setting the value of the attribute
>   [B}whenNoDataType[/B] for element jasperReport. The 3 accepted values
>   are: (a) NoPages (b) BlankPage (c) AllSectionsNoDetail

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To verify if the datasource is not the problem, you can put a static text in the `No Data` section of the report. Then in the report's properties

```
When No Data : No Data Section
```

If the static text is displayed in the report, then data source is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because the report has been compiled to compile it to click in Compile Report.