# The document has no pages. Jasper Report

Tags: java, swing, sql-server-2005, jasper-reports, netbeans-7

I'm having a problem searching for a solution to this issue. My codes works fine after I run it. It suppose to display the data on my sql database to my jtable, and there's a button that will trigger to display the jasper report but there's a little bit problem, it always shows me the message 'The document has no pages.' why is that? can someone help me with my issue here? What did I do wrong?

here is my codes:

```
package stringmanipulation;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;


public class r2xml extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public r2xml() {
        initComponents();
    }

Connection con;
    private void search() throws Exception{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:*****";
            String user = "******";
            String pass = "******";
            Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            Statement state = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT "
                    + "pIDNo AS 'Patient ID',"
                    + "pLName AS 'Last Name'," 
                    + "pFName AS 'First Name',"
                    + "pMI AS 'M.I.',"
                    + "pSex AS 'Sex',"
                    + "pStatus AS 'Status',"
                    + "pTelNo AS 'Contact No.',"
                    + "pDocID AS 'Doctor ID',"
                    + "pAddr AS 'St. No.',"
                    + "pStreet AS 'St. Name',"
                    + "pBarangay AS 'Barangay',"
                    + "pCity AS 'City',"
                    + " pProvince AS 'Province',"
                    + " pLNameKIN AS 'Last Name',"
                    + "pFNameKIN AS 'First Name',"
                    + "pMIKIN AS 'M.I.',"
                    + "pRelationKIN AS 'Relation',"
                    + "pTotalDue AS 'Total Due'"
                    + " FROM dbo.Patients");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
            DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
            Vector column_name = new Vector();
            Vector data_rows = new Vector();

            for (int i=1; i<columns;i++){
                column_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
            }
            dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(column_name);

            while(rs.next()){
                data_rows = new Vector();
                for (int j=1; j<columns; j++){
                data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
                }
                dtm.addRow(data_rows);
            }
            tblPatient.setModel(dtm);
    }

    public void reportviewer() {


        try{

        String report = "C:\\Users\\cleanfuel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\StringManipulation\\src\\stringmanipulation\\report1.jrxml";
        JasperReport jasp_report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
        JasperPrint jasp_print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasp_report, null, con);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasp_print);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {System.out.print(e);}
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")




public static void main(String args[]) {
        PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout("[%-5p] %C.%M:%L: %m%n");
        ConsoleAppender appender = new ConsoleAppender(pl);
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new r2xml().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

here is the XML report :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="71"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="PieChartDataset"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     Patients."pIDNo" AS Patients_pIDNo,
     Patients."pLName" AS Patients_pLName,
     Patients."pFName" AS Patients_pFName,
     Patients."pMI" AS Patients_pMI,
     Patients."pSex" AS Patients_pSex,
     Patients."pStatus" AS Patients_pStatus,
     Patients."pTelNo" AS Patients_pTelNo,
     Patients."pDocID" AS Patients_pDocID,
     Patients."pAddr" AS Patients_pAddr,
     Patients."pStreet" AS Patients_pStreet,
     Patients."pBarangay" AS Patients_pBarangay,
     Patients."pCity" AS Patients_pCity,
     Patients."pProvince" AS Patients_pProvince,
     Patients."pLNameKIN" AS Patients_pLNameKIN,
     Patients."pFNameKIN" AS Patients_pFNameKIN,
     Patients."pMIKIN" AS Patients_pMIKIN,
     Patients."pRelationKIN" AS Patients_pRelationKIN,
     Patients."pTotalDue" AS Patients_pTotalDue
FROM
     "dbo"."Patients" Patients]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Patients_pIDNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pLName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pFName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pMI" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pSex" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pStatus" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pTelNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pDocID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pAddr" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pStreet" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pBarangay" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pLNameKIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pFNameKIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pMIKIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pRelationKIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Patients_pTotalDue" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <group name="Patients_pIDNo">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pIDNo}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="31">
                <frame>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="72" y="7" width="730" height="24" forecolor="#B89F7D" backcolor="#70A9C6"/>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement style="SubTitle" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="155" y="1" width="110" height="23" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font fontName="Arial" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pIDNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="6"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band height="555" splitType="Stretch">
            <pie3DChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false" evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="-18" y="406" width="229" height="139"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <pieDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="PieChartDataset">
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(5)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <keyExpression><![CDATA[/* Replace with your key expression here */
$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></keyExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(200*Math.random()*5)]]></valueExpression>
                </pieDataset>
                <pie3DPlot>
                    <plot backgroundAlpha="0.5" foregroundAlpha="0.8">
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#3399FF"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#00CCFF"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="2" color="#0066CC"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="3" color="#6699FF"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="4" color="#004A94"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="5" color="#00356A"/>
                    </plot>
                    <itemLabel color="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                </pie3DPlot>
            </pie3DChart>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="65" width="229" height="250">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["flower1.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="-20" width="229" height="250">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} > 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["flower1.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="318" y="315" width="239" height="181" backcolor="#FFFFCC">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="4" leftPadding="4" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Each chart is populated on each page.
The 3 pie charts are currently using an empty datasource and the values are
generated using a random generator.

This rectangle element is not printed (see the print when expression of this
element)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="201" y="431" width="117" height="1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="3.0" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#996600"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="275" y="-10" width="240" height="181" backcolor="#FFFFCC">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="4" leftPadding="4" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CC9900"/>
                </box>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Flowers

There are two flowers, the first one is printed only starting from the second page, the other one only in the first page.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="72" y="37" width="204" height="1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="3.0" lineStyle="Dotted" lineColor="#996600"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="94" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="336" y="65" width="449" height="29"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="22" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Hospital ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="0" width="822" height="65" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#006699"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Title" x="231" y="0" width="578" height="65"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="54" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patient Form]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="210" y="0" width="575" height="14"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="99" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pSex]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="132" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pStatus]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="165" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pTelNo]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="198" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pDocID]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="231" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pAddr]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="264" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pStreet]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="297" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pBarangay]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="330" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pCity]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="363" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pProvince]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="396" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pLNameKIN]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="429" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pFNameKIN]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="462" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pMIKIN]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="495" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pRelationKIN]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="528" y="0" width="33" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Patients_pTotalDue]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="72" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ Last Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="72" y="0" width="65" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" positionType="Float" x="137" y="0" width="74" height="14" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Middle Initial]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="227" y="14" width="575" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="226" y="0" width="575" height="14"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="99" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pSex}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="132" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="165" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pTelNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="198" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pDocID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="231" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pAddr}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="264" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pStreet}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="297" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pBarangay}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="330" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="363" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pProvince}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="396" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pLNameKIN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="429" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pFNameKIN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="462" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pMIKIN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="495" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pRelationKIN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="528" y="0" width="33" height="14"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pTotalDue}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="4" y="0" width="68" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pLName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="72" y="1" width="65" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pFName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Detail" positionType="Float" x="137" y="1" width="72" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Patients_pMI}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="2" y="0" width="800" height="16" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#006699"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="753" y="0" width="40" height="16" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="673" y="0" width="80" height="16" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="2" y="0" width="197" height="16" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Are you able to post the `report1.jrxml` as well?  Does the query return any results?

Comment: I have report1.jrxml sir, and if I click Preview it shows me the JasperReport the way I want it, I also re-arrange it already (I already assumed that it will works fine because I follow the the tutorial right, but I'm wrong.)

Comment: Can include the file as part of your question?  That way we might be able to download it and have a look - or construct a simple version

Comment: how can I do that sir?

Comment: The report is an XML file, open it in a text editor, copy the contents and edit your question to included, just like you did with your source code

Comment: kindly look at the edit sir @MadProgrammer, is that it?

Comment: A few things come to mind. You define `con` twice.  Once as private class field and once within in the `search` method.  This means that the `con` you use in the `reportviewer` method may be `null`, also, you're not closing your database resources when your finished with them...

Comment: can you teach me how to fix the con issue and how to close it? sir @MadProgrammer

Comment: I did it! it's the con issue!, I place Connection conn

and then I edit the Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

to conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

Comment: ! Awesome ! Well done !

Comment: the problem now is the loading, should I do another question sir @MadProgrammer ?? :D this becoming a bad habit eh?

Comment: because it takes approximately 15secs to display the `Jasper Report`, is it really like that?

Comment: We have one that can take over 30 minutes to compile, you're lucky;).  Give me a few minutes, I'll update my answer with some ideas

Comment: Maybe it's because my `database` don't have a large data. Ok sir @MadProgrammer I'll wait :)

Comment: I've added a simple concept of a `SwingWorker`.  I don't think you can speed up the process greatly, but this will stop the UI from looking like it's hung

Comment: Sir @MadProgrammer can you spare some time in discussion room? I need to tell you something

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28086/discussion-between-crystal-maiden-and-madprogrammer)

Comment: This may help you in this case... [ The Document has no page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47102519/4783846)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, resource management...

You should only open a single connection to the database if you can.  Make sure you close it before the application is closed.  The connection process can be expensive, so you only really want to do it when you absolutely have to...

You close your resources once you have finished with them.  This is best achieved by using a `try-finally` block...

```
private Connection con;

protected void close() throws SQLException {
    if (con != null) {
        con.close();
    }
}

protected Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    if (con == null) {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:*****";
        String user = "******";
        String pass = "******";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    }
    return con;
}

private void search() throws Exception {

    Statement state = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        state = getConnection().createStatement();

        rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT "
                + "pIDNo AS 'Patient ID',"
                + "pLName AS 'Last Name',"
                + "pFName AS 'First Name',"
                + "pMI AS 'M.I.',"
                + "pSex AS 'Sex',"
                + "pStatus AS 'Status',"
                + "pTelNo AS 'Contact No.',"
                + "pDocID AS 'Doctor ID',"
                + "pAddr AS 'St. No.',"
                + "pStreet AS 'St. Name',"
                + "pBarangay AS 'Barangay',"
                + "pCity AS 'City',"
                + " pProvince AS 'Province',"
                + " pLNameKIN AS 'Last Name',"
                + "pFNameKIN AS 'First Name',"
                + "pMIKIN AS 'M.I.',"
                + "pRelationKIN AS 'Relation',"
                + "pTotalDue AS 'Total Due'"
                + " FROM dbo.Patients");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        Vector column_name = new Vector();
        Vector data_rows = new Vector();

        for (int i = 1; i < columns; i++) {
            column_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
        }
        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(column_name);

        while (rs.next()) {
            data_rows = new Vector();
            for (int j = 1; j < columns; j++) {
                data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
            }
            dtm.addRow(data_rows);
        }
        tblPatient.setModel(dtm);
        
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            state.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Now to the problem at hand...

It appears you have created two references to `con`.  One as class field and one as a method variable (in `search`).

You are then passing `con` to Jasper Reports, which I suspect is `null`.  Instead you should use the `getConnection()` as outlined above.

```
public void reportviewer() {
    try{
        String report = "C:\\Users\\cleanfuel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\StringManipulation\\src\\stringmanipulation\\report1.jrxml";
        JasperReport jasp_report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
        JasperPrint jasp_print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasp_report, null, getConnection());
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasp_print);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Updated with background worker...**

A report can take some time to compile and fill.  You should off load this work to a background thread so it doesn't interfere with your UI (or make it look like you application as hung).

The simplest solution would be to use a `SwingWorker`.  It has functionality to resync the threads with the UI

```
public void reportviewer() {
    // Disable any UI components you don't want the user using while
    // the report generates...
    new ReportWorker().execute();
}

public class ReportWorker extends SwingWorker<JasperPrint, Void> {

    @Override
    protected JasperPrint doInBackground() throws Exception {
        String report = "C:\\Users\\cleanfuel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\StringManipulation\\src\\stringmanipulation\\report1.jrxml";
        JasperReport jasp_report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
        JasperPrint jasp_print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasp_report, null, getConnection());
        return jasp_print;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            JasperPrint jasp_print = get();
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasp_print);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Renable any UI components you disabled before the report run
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

**Hints**

If you can pre-compile the report and load it (rather the loading the XML), it will make the report process quicker.