# Jasper Report Error: The report has no Pages

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am sure similar questions as the above have been asked but the provided answers seem not to address or solve my issues here. I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964552/the-document-has-no-pages-jasper-report) and followed [this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydNRavmbzWU) but all seems fine and yet my application is not working.

**I created a report in `iReport-5.6.0` and it is working fine, I mean it is displaying the report as expected. Now the problem comes when I want to open this same report in Java code...it is saying** "The document has no pages".

From my reading I understand that this has to do with my data source or something related to that but I cannot fix it.

**My Java Code**

This code is one I am using to run my reports.

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        conn = con.getConnection();
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("transrep1.jrxml"));
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**My JRXML**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="transrep" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3b8454da-c73e-44b5-8419-6b700bb7a5cb">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select *
from transactions
Where cashier='jill']]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="inv_number" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="barcode" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="sku" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="discount" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="line_price" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="date" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cash" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="card" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cheque" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="other" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="total_amount" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="cashier" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="55" uuid="42374cc0-37f3-45a4-9a48-018a149d5098"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Transactions by Cashier]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="012eb72f-85e5-430a-91d9-fc498cff5b66"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="92" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="4736ffa3-2266-43e0-a3ad-7d292f049f26"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoice #]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="184" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="50dec793-43ff-49ee-91ed-469584c4c5b6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[SKU]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="276" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="73110a66-5b8a-4cbc-a5f1-a0bced23b51f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Quantity]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="368" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="35565309-8ede-415c-83d1-e74f6248fdb5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="460" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="06e79d8b-1789-4586-b7bd-3cbbb8a325ef"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cashier]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="e2b6453b-900e-4790-8de4-f7145b483b50"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="92" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="ad12a306-7ab3-4e38-b339-2c7607093955"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{inv_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="184" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="fdf9efa8-5849-49d3-b91e-8f822e4675e1"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sku}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="276" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="0843372f-078c-4a93-9bbb-34fb4a1c42ad"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="368" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="ddf7abde-9ea0-4c94-8b7e-aba789dec10e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total_amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="460" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="d4aaedef-1880-40cd-b6f1-f4d5eaac587a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cashier}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="49" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="210" y="27" width="80" height="20" uuid="7cbceb70-1224-4afc-acfb-4a50a937320b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="334" y="27" width="40" height="20" uuid="07b25ad8-d771-41f3-81f3-8c57bd529025"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**So what have I done wrong?**

Comment: 1) Maybe you using wrong template (from Java code); 2) Maybe you are using wrong connection

Comment: @AlexK As to template, I am certain it is one

Comment: @AlexK So it was connection! I been on this issue since yesterday! Thanks, you saved my day!