# IReport Document Has No Pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I have encountered same problem 'Document Has No Pages' issue as described in [Jasper Reports And IReport Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769916/jasper-reports-and-ireport-issue). I applied the solution provided in the given link and it started working. I am stuck behind the concept. My main point of concern is, when we are using detail band and we don't give a data query it gives `Document has No Pages` error. As soon as we give a dummy query in data query, it starts working. Kindly note that, i am using a subDataSet for a table component. That's where IReport generates this issue. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: You did not provide the sample to reproduce your issue. How we can help you?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that **This is not an error** but this is how it is configured to do.
This happens when you don't have results to display in the report from the database. But still you can set option what to do in this situation.

In Jaspersoft iReport 5.6.0

```
 1. right click the report
 2. Go to properties
 3. Find **When No Data**
 4. Select one from the options
```

There you'll see some options as **No Section**, **No Detail**, **Blank Page**, **No Data Section**, **No pages**.

Choose the one suits you. -_(--)-_